# Error in One-to-many Relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, one-to-many

I have the following tables

```
Users
----------
UserId (int)
Name (varchar)

Stores
----------
StoreId (int)
Name (varchar)
Owner (int) (FK to UserId in Users table)
```

and the following entities in the edmx file

```
User{
     properties
     UserId
     Name
}

Store{
     properties
     StoreId
     Name
     Owner
     navigation proeprties
     User
}
```

I am using a POCO approach. Mapping the edmx file to my POCO entities. Fetching Users works fine, but when I try to create a new user it gets saved in the database successfully but throws the following exception

> "The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be
>   in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Metadata
>   information for the relationship 'FK_Stores_Users_Owner' could not be
>   retrieved. If mapping attributes are used, make sure that the
>   EdmRelationshipAttribute for the relationship has been defined in the
>   assembly.  When using convention-based mapping, metadata information
>   for relationships between detached entities cannot be determined.
>   Parameter name: relationshipName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using EF 4.1 together with EDMX, then you have to declare the Key constrains by yourself either use attributes or Fluent-API. Since EF 4.1 is not compatible with traditional constraint configuration defined in XML.

Furthermore, make sure you use "ADO.NET DbContext generator" rather than "ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator".

Comment: I think EF has a long way to go. Was quite happy using NHibernate. :(

Comment: I think EF does better job as long as you know how to find alternative to what EF can't do.